# MySql statement to create new table only works when limited to less than 100k entries

Tags: mysql

If i limit query1 to 100k this script will create a new table, but if I try and transfer all 300k entries it fails without error. any suggestions?

```php
$query1 =  "SELECT DISTINCT city, region FROM geolocations";
$result = mysql_query($query1);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //create array of ids to select from DB
    $id_arr[] = $row['location_id'];
}

mysql_free_result($result);     

//join the array to create SELECT statement 
$ids = join(',',$id_arr);  
//create new table using data associated with locations_ids in id_arr
$query2 = "CREATE TABLE clean_gls SELECT * FROM geolocations WHERE location_id IN ($ids) "; 
mysql_query($query2);
```

Comment: You first `select` doesn't name a column `location_id`. I'm not clear as to how you're accumulating anything in `$id_arr`.

Comment: Did you check the PHP log? Maybe you are hitting the memory limit? Your script does not output anything, how do you know it failed?

Comment: I know it failed b/c when I limit to 100k it creates table with all the data in place, but when try to increase limit, no table is created. Where do i find php log?

Comment: check php log no errors there either

Comment: Probably running into mysql's max_allowed_packet limit, which puts a hard limit on how long a query string can be.

Comment: -Marc B. I raised the limit of the max_allowed_packet in my.cnf. No solution.

Comment: Your example code is non-functional and doesn't illustrate the problem you're describing. $row will only have city and region in it, yet you're trying to pull location_id out of it. That's not going to work.

Comment: Tim - If I change query1 to $query1 = "SELECT DISTINCT city, region FROM geolocations LIMIT 100000"; A new table is created with 100000 rows and all the data is ok. The problem arises if I remove the LIMIT 100000, I want all 300k DISTINCT rows from geolocations copied to the clean_gls table.

Comment: Mat - If I add location_id to the DISTINCT selection statement my query is no longer distinct b/c every row has a DISTINCT location_id.

Answer (score 1):

As Mat said, there appears to be something missing from your code, but you should really look into using a join or subquery to generate your array of location ids, so that all the processing is done by the server.

EDIT:

So, I still don't understand how you're getting location_id from your original query, but maybe this will do what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE clean_gls (PRIMARY KEY (city, region)) IGNORE SELECT * FROM geolocations
```

If `IGNORE` isn't what you want, try `REPLACE`.

Comment: "SELECT DISTINCT city, region FROM geolocations"; This statement fills my array with the locations_ids no problem. If i print_r() all data is there. If i include location_id in the SELECT statement ex. "SELECT DISTINCT city, region, location_id FROM geolocations" the row is no longer distinct.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, you have issues with your original code:

- You are not selecting location_id, so you cannot create an array of
  location_id
- Why are you pulling all these ids into php only to pass
  them back to mysql?

If you are trying to put distinct city and region combinations into your new table then do it with a single database execution similar to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE clean_gls
SELECT DISTINCT city, region
FROM geolocations
```

Answer (score 0):

This query worked I wanted to select distinct city, region combinations and group it with its associated data in the new table.

```
CREATE TABLE clean_gls SELECT * FROM geolocations GROUP BY city, region;
```

Comment: You're not getting all your data with that query. Selecting * and grouping by two columns doesn't even execute in most databases. For instance: If you have New York, New York in geolocations twice with 2 different location_ids, you're only going to get one of those location_ids back and which one it is will be essentially decided randomly.

Comment: Tim I understand using group will decide randomly and that is ok for my solution. I require only one entry per city and which one is chosen makes no difference.